# What will be $\partial K\ $?

Tags: general-topology, operator-algebras, connectedness, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

> Let $A$ be a complex Banach algebra and $a \in A.$ Let $\sigma(a)$ denote the spectrum of $a.$ Let $V$ be the union of all bounded connected components of $\sigma (a)^c.$ Let $K = \sigma (a) \cup V.$ Then show that $\partial K = \partial (\sigma (a)).$

We know that $\partial K \subseteq \partial (\sigma (a)) \cup \partial V.$ Also since $\sigma(a)^c \subseteq_{\text {open}} \mathbb C$ it's components are all open and their boundaries are all contained in $\sigma(a).$ Hence $\partial V \subseteq \sigma (a).$  So $\partial K \subseteq \sigma (a),$ since $\partial (\sigma (a)) \subseteq \overline {\sigma (a)} = \sigma (a),$ as $\sigma (a)$ is closed. But I can't conclude anything more than that. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.